# Named a table "order" in Microsoft Office Access database and the webapp now can't see the table (even after renaming it)

Tags: database, asp-classic

I am creating a web application in Dreamweaver using ASP VBScript. The web application is a store and I have to implement a database into it (which I did). I created a table in my database called "order" and for some reason I couldn't dynamically enter the data from a record set that I wanted to.

I searched on Google and came across someone saying that "order" is a reserved word and that I should name my table something else. I did so several times, using several different names, and even created new tables with the same fields, thinking I could use this table, but no luck. Ever since, whenever I try to create a new recordset I am only picking up the old table (the one named "order", the other two tables are working fine):

[image]

I couldn't see the new renamed table fields when creating a recordset no matter how much I refreshed the database window!

[image]

I am able to access the database that I WANT to use when I double-click the database through Local view OR Remote View (I can't find the old DB anywhere). The problems arises when I want to use the data from the "order" recordset (since this is the recordset it is forcing me to use even though I cant). I am getting this error when I press on the + button of the recordset that is related to the order table: `[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in FROM clause.` SO when I go and change this code to the name of an existing table in my DB (which is now orders)  I then get this error: `[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'Orders'.  Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly`.

Here's the DB:
[image]

Here's the code where the problem is:

```
<!--#include file="Connections/cnFreshNew.asp" -->
<%
Dim rsProducts
Dim rsProducts_cmd
Dim rsProducts_numRows

Set rsProducts_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rsProducts_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_cnFreshNew_STRING
rsProducts_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Products" 
rsProducts_cmd.Prepared = true

Set rsProducts = rsProducts_cmd.Execute
rsProducts_numRows = 0
%>
<%
Dim rsUsers
Dim rsUsers_cmd
Dim rsUsers_numRows

Set rsUsers_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rsUsers_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_cnFreshNew_STRING
rsUsers_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Users" 
rsUsers_cmd.Prepared = true

Set rsUsers = rsUsers_cmd.Execute
rsUsers_numRows = 0
%>
<%
Dim Recordset1
Dim Recordset1_cmd
Dim Recordset1_numRows

Set Recordset1_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
Recordset1_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_cnFreshNew_STRING
Recordset1_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Orders" 
Recordset1_cmd.Prepared = true

Set Recordset1 = Recordset1_cmd.Execute
Recordset1_numRows = 0
%>
```

I can't create a brand new DB and start over because I need my lectures login credentials as it is on the college's server and it's a bit too late to do that now, sadly.

Am I screwed?

Comment: Hi COYG, can you upload your images into StackOverflow itself, please? I can't see them where I am.

Comment: @Paul Hi, sorry for the late reply just seen your comment, I uploaded them into StackOverflow itself now.

Comment: You refer to the table as `order` throughout your post, but `orders` in the code.  Have you tried simply changing the code to `Recordset1_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Order]"` *(PS: notice I've enclosed the `Order` field in square brackets)*

Comment: What's the content of the `MM_cnFreshNew_STRING` string - that will tell you where your database is located. Try `Response.Write(MM_cnFreshNew_STRING)`.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to designate it as a table and not a predetermined variable or word that means somethig in sql is to use brackets, try

SELECT * 
FROM [order]
WHERE 1=1;